# How to replace getExternalStorageDirectory() by getExternalFilesDir in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am practicing with `MediaRecorder` and when I use `getExternalStorageDirectory ()` I see this warning `getExternalStorageDirectory (): File! is deprecated`.
I have investigates and suggest me to use `getExternalFilesDir`, the problem is that I don't know how.

My code

```
val path: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/grabacion.mp3"
```

Comment: Just try to use it and you will succeed.

Comment: I have replaced **val path: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (). toString () + "/ recording.mp3"** by 
**val path: String = getExternalFilesDir("").toString() + "/grabacion.mp3"**
I would like to know if Okay, but please ask for your help to correct it

Comment: Very well indeed. Or getExternalFilesDir (null).

Comment: Yes, but I have a doubt, why when using getExternalStorageDirectory () I must use Environment and in getExternalFilesDir (null) I don't use it and it works.I have put null and it works too, but I would like you to help me with my question

Comment: The first one is a static function of the Environment class. The second one a member of the Context class. You dont have to mention the context as within your Activity that is known.